# how to display a view controller in full screen in iPad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller, fullscreen

i have a view controller which i wants to display it in full screen, these view has tab bar items, below is the two statements which i used to present the view in full Screen:

```
    EditMomViewController *momctr=[[EditMomViewController alloc]init];
    momctr.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentModalViewController:momctr animated:YES];
```

but it doesn't work, any idea about doing that will be helpful,thanks.

Comment: You have to call that when you create the view controller (app delegate, viewWillAppear); else it doesn't work.

Comment: You should simply just make an universal app... In xCode use tabbed viewcontroller UNIVERSAL.

Comment: No, i want to display the view in full screen programatically , (i.e. 1 button presents the view in full screen and another button exits full screen , etc)

Answer (score 1):

You could present it as a modal viewcontroller which will not show the tabs. I'm not sure if that lines up with your intent but it is a definite way to go full screen. Do this inside of the root VC in which you want to show the modal:

```
[self presentModalViewController:theOtherViewController animated:YES];
```

Comment: did it show up in a small window? If so, try changing the modalPresentationStyle of the view to be presented

Comment: momctr.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationFullScreen;

Answer (score 0):

The `tabBar`'s content view does not fill full screen, so your `ViewController`'s view also can not overlap whole screen. I do not suggest to play with view's frame or parent, since it would not be stable solution. Instead of this, create an intermediate view with all your content. When you need full screen mode, place this intermediate view right to the root window, and put it back to your `ViewController`'s view in other cases.

```
-(void) setFullScreen:(BOOL)fullScreen {
    if(fullScreen) {
        [self.view.window addSubview:intermediateView];
        intermediateView.frame = self.view.window.bounds;
    } else {
        [self.view addSubview:intermediateView];
        intermediateView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    }
}
```

Comment: what's the type of intermediateView ?

Comment: Define `UIView* intermediateView` instance var of your class and initialize it with all subviews in `viewDidLoad` method. Also you can load it from XIB.